# Prompt Customization Query - PS1='[\u@\h]\!:echo $? $ '

Tags: prompt, bashrc, ps1

If in .bashrc the following reports the 'history number of the current command' (and the exit code of the last command), how can I configure it to report the 'history number of the previous command'?

```
PS1='[\u@\h]\!:`echo $?` $ '
```

Comment: Did you try subtracting 1?

Comment: I'm not sure if I undertand how the syntax would follow on that.  Can you explain?  Thanks:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting one from the history number can be done like this:

```
PS1='[\u@\h] $((\! -1)):`echo $?` $ '
```

So that will show the return code of the history entry listed, which makes the prompt look more consistant I imagine.

Comment: @user98496 Please **accept this answer** by clicking the green checkmark if it worked for you. Thanks!